# No funciona websockets con un servidor publicado

Tags: php, javascript

me refiero a que no funcionan los websockets cuando intento publicar con port forwarding mi sitio. Lo que hice fue en el main.js cambiar 'ws://localhost:8080' por 'ws://myapp.hopto.org:8080' myapp viene siendo el nombre de mi sitio...
Obtengo este error en la consola
WebSocket connection to 'ws://myapp.hopto.org:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Y en cmd simplemente no llega ninguna conexión nueva

Este es mi código

Main.js(cliente)

```js
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://myapp.hopto.org:8080');
var name;
var last;
conn.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

function getTime() {
    var date = new Date();

    return date.toLocaleDateString()
};

function sendMessage(id) {
    conn.send(id);
  console.log("sendedMessage " + id);
};

function receiveMessage(id) {
  var id = JSON.parse(id.data);
leerNuevosMensajesGlobal(id);

console.log("ReceivedMessage " + id);
};

conn.onmessage = function (id) {
    receiveMessage(id);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
});

function scrollBottom(divName){
    var objDiv = document.getElementById(divName);
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

Chat-server.php(servidor)

```html
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use App\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

Intenté con otros puertos pero no los puedo desbloquear, solo se desbloquea el 80
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio el 80 sí sale abierto, intenté poniendo "end port" 92 tampoco. Ni poniendo solo el 92 sin poner el 80, también intenté con otros 84 86 etc

Comment: Olvidé decir que el sitio "myapp.hopto.org" funciona correctamente, este muestra lo que se mostraría si pusieran mi ip

Comment: Esta pregunta es bastante util, no se la respuesta porque no he trabajado con websockets ni con sockets creados desde PHP, asi que simplemente apoyare tu pregunta dandole un voto arriba porque a muchos usuarios puede servirles esta informacion para sus proyectos algun dia.

Comment: Tu tienes abierto ese puerto en el firewall de tu servidor?

Comment: Pues lo que yo hice fue abrir el puerto en la página del router y en el firewall de windows. Aunque tengo deshabilitado el firewall. Cuando pongo netstat -a en el cmd aparece todo correctamente, si tengo el servidor iniciado aparece el puerto y sino no aparece.  También configuré esto
   public function __construct($httpHost = 'myapp.hopto.org', $port = 8080, $address = '0.0.0.0', LoopInterface $loop = null) {